# Joining data from two CSV files using PySpark

Tags: pyspark, mapreduce

I have two huge CSV files, and I need to inner join the data from two CSV and then do some processing on the result. My question is what is the most efficient way to do so?
This is what I did:

```
df1 = spark.read.csv('df1.csv', sep=r'\t', header=True)
df2 = spark.read.csv('df2.csv', sep=r'\t', header=True)

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("d1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("d2")

query = """SELECT d1.id, d2.id, d1.name, d2.title
            FROM d1
            INNER JOIN d2
            ON d1.id = d2.id;
            """

results = spark.sql(query)
```

Is there any more efficient way to read and process them, for example using map/reduce?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to walking's answer unlike RDD, dataframe don't have Map or reduce functions as those steps are handled by spark in backend but there are some optimizations and hints for joining dataframes which are useful to know if you know what kind of data you are dealing with.

For e.g - If you have lot of nulls in joining keys it will be better to filter them out before joining

Another e.g- In some specific cases like when keys are not sortable Shuffle hash Join hint will give better performance than Sort merge Join which if you have time and resources can check by running both

Some good articles to learn about spark join are listed [here](https://medium.com/@sukulmahadik/spark-join-and-optimizations-e8b926a7d6f)

Answer (score 0):

nothing wrong with what you are doing, you can also use spark directly without spark sql:

```
df1.join(df2, on='id').select('id', 'name', 'title')
```